# Citation MWE example doesn't work

Tags: bibliographies, apa-style

I have a problem with apa6, apacite, etc. In the process of creating a mwe, I ran across code here on this site as a mwe, but it doesn't work. When compiled (Texpad on a Mac, using Bibtex), it produces [?] as the citation.

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @book{Knu86,
    author = {Knuth, Donald E.},
    year = {1986},
    title = {The \TeX book},
  }
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

Doesn't work. \cite{Knu86}

\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Thanks for any help on the mwe so I can post my real problem.

Comment: after running latex, bibtex must run to produce a `.bbl` file, then latex twice more.  (the first latex run puts the reference info into the log file for bibtex to use; bibtex creates the `.bbl` file, the first post-bibtex latex run reads the `.bbl` file and puts the biblio labels into the new `.aux` file, and the last latex run picks up these labels and resolves the `\cite`s.  with fewer runs of latex, in the proper sequence with bibtex, there isn't enough information to fill in the `\cite` info, and you get `??` instead.)

Comment: See also [Question mark instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63852/question-mark-instead-of-citation-number).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also need a `\bibliographystyle`. And compile several times, like @barbarabeeton explained. This works:

```
\documentclass{article}

% Update 2022: Not needed anymore.
%\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @book{Knu86,
    author = {Knuth, Donald E.},
    year = {1986},
    title = {The \TeX book},
  }
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

This works, yeah! \cite{Knu86}

\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\jobname` indded is a valid TeX command. It expands to the main file's name (w/o .tex). It can be used in this context. see TeXbook (or `texbytopic` or `source2e`)

Comment: So i'll reundo my downvote;)