# How to change the bracketed references at the end of an article to parenthesis, i.e., [1] to (1).

Tags: cross-referencing

How to change the bracketed references at the end of an article to parenthesis, i.e., [1] to (1). The journal in question wants (1) at end of the article not [1] which I get with latex \article.

Comment: You have not mentioned what class you're using, nor what packages you're using to set your references. Perhaps this is the motivation behind you asking the "same question" over and over?

Comment: @barbarabeeton: That deals with citing, not the actual references. However, clarification is required.

Comment: We need some MWE (minimum working example) code before we can help, for example [like this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111132/citation-mwe-example-doesnt-work)

Comment: As noted, this is the same as your previous question, and both are without some other detail dupes of a much older one.